# How to get the first two octets in an IP address Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

E.g., IP = '10.11.12.13'
I want to extract '10.11.' or everything except what comes after the 2nd '.'

Comment: what the field type ?

Comment: I think it is a string. Not very good with SQL, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex solution : 
`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR("youField", '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.') AS "output"`

check at http://rextester.com/DJN6158

Answer (score 2):

I know you have an accepted answer but just for completeness here's an option without REGEX;

```
SELECT SUBSTR(your_field,1,INSTR(your_field,'.',1,2)-1)
FROM dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `regexp_substr` using the perl \d digit operator...

```
    with ip_addresses(ip) as
    (
      select '10.11.234.11' from dual union all
      select '253.22.1.93' from dual union all
      select '2.345.98.23' from dual
    )
    select ip,
           regexp_substr(ip, '^\d+\.\d+\.') as truncated_ip
    from ip_addresses;
```